# Angular2 value is not binding with model while using event.preventDefault()

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have created input directive for validation. In that, I am using event.preventDefault() for not to allow pressed key.

Following is my code:

```
<input class="input" maxlength="255" [(ngModel)]="chargeLabel" inputRestrictor pattern="^\\w+( \\w+)*$" singleSpace="false" />
```

Input Directive Code:

```
export class InputRestrictorDirective {

    @Input('inputRestrictor') inputRestrictor: any;
    @Input('pattern') pattern: string;
    @Input() singleSpace = 'true';
    private regex: RegExp;

    // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
    // Backspace, tab, end, home
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
        this.regex = new RegExp(this.pattern, 'g');
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }

        let inputValue: any = event.target.value + event.key;
        if (inputValue.match(this.regex) === null && inputValue !== '') {
            if (this.singleSpace === 'true') {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            } else {
                inputValue = inputValue.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '');
                event.target.value = inputValue;
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that whatever values I enter in textbox is not stored in model but if I press specials key like backspace or tab than it will be stored in model. Means value is bind with model. Can you help out?

Comment: add timeout, hope it will work

Comment: How can I add timeout here? its executed in keypress event.

Comment: import `TimerWrapper` and  add `TimerWrapper.setTimeout(() => {  
   event.preventDefault();
}, 100);` inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this. I just need to put condition in directive file.

```
if (inputValue.match(/\s\s+/g)) {
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '');
    this.el.nativeElement.value = inputValue;
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
}
```

If there is any double space in inputbox than I need to use preventDefault().

Comment: If you've got the solution by yourself mark your answer as correct one and don't edit your question by adding that fix in it.